# Why was the recent "Nahel Marzouk Protest" more violent than the BLM protest?

Tags: france

The **Black Lives Matter (BLM)** protests began in 2013 as a response to the acquittal of George Zimmerman in the shooting death of Trayvon Martin, a black teenager. The movement gained national attention in 2014 after the deaths of Michael Brown in Ferguson, Missouri, and Eric Garner in New York City. These deaths, along with several others, sparked protests across the United States and around the world, calling for an end to police brutality against black people and systemic racism.

On 27 June 2023, **Nahel Merzouk**, a French 17-year-old of Moroccan and Algerian descent, was shot and killed by police in Nanterre, a suburb of Paris, France. Initial reporting on the incident, informed by police statements, was later contradicted by a video posted online, which led to widespread protests and riots. Symbols of the state such as town halls, schools, police stations, and other buildings were attacked. The Interior Ministry reported that more than 5,000 vehicles had been set on fire, along with 10,000 garbage cans; nearly 1,000 buildings had been burnt, damaged, or looted; 250 police stations and gendarmeries had been attacked; and more than 700 police officers had been injured.

Can we compare the recent [Nahel Marzouk Protest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nahel_Merzouk_protests) in France and the [BLM protests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violence_and_controversies_during_the_George_Floyd_protests)?

Why was the French protest more violent than the BLM protests?

Comment: What is "the BLM riot"? There have been many protests associated with the Black Lives Matter movement, of which most have been non-violent, but there have also been a few in which isolated individuals did engage in some violence. Which of those do you consider "the BLM riot"?

Comment: What do you mean by the recent French riot? What do you mean by the BLM riot? Please add more details then a link to a wiki page for an event that had multiple riots associated with it.

Comment: Because one is a riot and the other is a protest?

Comment: Can you please put details from both of those wiki articles in your question? Users should not be expected to read multiple wiki articles in order to determine what you are asking.

Comment: France has a long tradition of violent political protests, dating at least back to 1968.  Property crimes are sometimes, by some at least, claimed as part of the necessary arsenal of political freedom.  Cars get torched on New Year's Eves in the hundreds, after lost football matches.  Look at Gilets Jaunes.  On a recent answer of mine re. pension reforms I was criticized in comments for stating that the protesters had gone too far in destroying property.  Given all that, it makes sense that after this police screw up, the demonstrations would be amped up.

Comment: https://www.tf1info.fr/justice-faits-divers/vehicules-incendies-voitures-brulees-lors-du-nouvel-an-2023-que-disent-reellement-les-chiffres-du-ministre-de-l-interieur-gerald-darmanin-sur-la-criminalite-2243830.html  :  only 690 cars torched NYE 2023, much better than 874 2022.  Yay!  Progress!

Comment: Someone torching a car in France can reasonably presume they won't be shot dead, either by police, or counter-protestors

Comment: Re. close votes. This site has tons of questions about BLM-related events. Comparing their circumstances, with which many people will have some familiarity, with the recent riots - of political significance - in France, seems reasonable for this site. Especially as the root causes - wrongful police killings - are identical.